# Group by "original order" causes looping in crystal report 11

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report grouped by Themes-S >> Questions-S there are 8 themes and each theme has a between 17 and 5 questions in it.

The report has 16 pages.

I need to change the ordering from `specific` to `original` when I do I end up with 288 pages

Something is looping? I can not figure out how to fix this
(using CR 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just might have a very unoptimized original order, with page break properties set on start/end of group.  For example, if your database stores records for 'country' in this order:

```
Canada
Canada
USA
Canada
USA
Canada
USA
```

Then with specific order "USA", "Canada", you'd have only 2 groups. With original order, however, you'd have 6 groups. Since the group is changing on (almost) every record, it might seem like it's "looping" over the values, repeating them again.

If you don't want it to do this, you can either (a) not use original order, or (b) change your source data to be better organized.